# LinkButton onclick event in repeater in updatepanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onclick, click

I can use Click event in a repeater, repeater is in an updatepanel. I am using div as trigger that is trying to click to LinkButton.

```
protected void rpt_product_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div_product = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("div_product");
    LinkButton lnk_product = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnk_product");
    lnk_product.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
    lnk_product.ID = "lnk_product_" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1);
    div_product.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + lnk_product.ClientID + "').click()");
}
```

Getting Errors in a Browser:

> Image (async)     
>   _updatePanel    @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _scriptIncludesLoadComplete @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   (anonymous) @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   (anonymous) @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _loadScriptsInternal    @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _nextSession    @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   loadScripts @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _onFormSubmitCompleted  @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   (anonymous) @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   (anonymous) @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   completed   @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _onReadyStateChange @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
>   executeRequest  @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   executeRequest  @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   invoke  @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _onFormSubmit   @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   _doPostBack @   ScriptResource.axd?d…YI5aZ0&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   (anonymous) @   ScriptResource.axd?d…qOX341&t=3d6efc1f:5 
>   (anonymous) @   VM7570:1

Do you have any idea? How can i use javascript click event without any problem. if user clicks to the div, i would like to click to the link button.

Updatepanel > Repeater > Div > LinkButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the Repeater (I think, it would really help if you posted that also next time).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_product" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rpt_product_ItemCreated">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="div_product" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_product" runat="server" OnClick="lnk_product_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                     Div Contents
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem probably is that you are changing the ID of the LinkButton. So remove `lnk_product.ID = "lnk_product_" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1);`. You don't need to change it. Then it will work.